# Conditional Formatting Based on Single Cell Across Columns and Rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find a single formula for conditional formatting based on a single cells value next to a section of cells. This would include both rows and columns, as well as sections next and below each section. This section would check to see if the single cell contains a particular name, which would be corresponded to a particular color.

In my example sheet, I have single cells containing a name (B2, H2, B7, H7), which corresponds to the ranges next to the cell (B2 -> D3:F5, H2 -> J3:L5, B7 -> D8:F10, H7 -> J8:L10). I'm looking for single formula that would apply to all ranges checking for a name, for example =$B$2="John" would be the color RED in each of the cell sections (D3:F5, J3:L5, D8:F10, J8:L10).

Is it possible to have a single formula for both sections horizontally AND vertically, or can it only be horizontally OR vertically? The names in B2, H2, B7, H7 can interchange, so I'm trying to make the colored regions dynamic.

Test Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LLXNtMbwyDSe3Kl3y_q_l6hEsmpSGXX1h26-Ad5X8JM/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Please let me know if that makes sense? Thanks!

Comment: I think you will need to create set of conditional formula for each region, but unlikely you can copy and apply to the entire sheet rather than do it region by region, then it shall work

Comment: So what would be the appearance you are going for if cell `b2` = `John`? What about if  `b2` = `bob`, would you expect `D3:F5` by purple?

Comment: I would like to be able to create 4 separate rules (one for each name) for the the entire sheet. The range would only cover the regions in the white boxes (D3:F5, J3:L5, D8:F10, J8:L10). I'm trying to avoid creating four separate rules per region. If it's not possible for the entire sheet, if I could do a per row (top two regions then bottom two regions) or per column (left two regions then right two regions), that would be sufficient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your conditional formula working on a grup of cells, you have to build an algorithm to reference them.
Then you use custom formula in conditional formatting.

First - define a reference:
I use ADDRESS formula to determine source cell from which information about formatting will be taken.

```
=address(5*int((row()-1)/5)+2,6*int((column()-2)/6)+2,4)
```

It means that for each row smaller than seven display 2 then display 7th and so on (works for bigger tables)
And for each colmumn index smaller than eighy display 2 then display 8th, etc.
Number 4 here determines only notation (A1 notation).

[image]

When I am sure that all the references are correct I can empty cells and leave space for real content.

While you have this reference, you can make 4 different Conditional formats.
Each should work for all ranges.
So in field "Apply to range" you write them all:

D3:F5,J3:L5,D8:F10,J8:L10

Then you choose Custom Formula to format cells. It goes:

=Indirect(address(5*int((row()-1)/5)+2,6*int((column()-2)/6)+2,4))="John"

This means that for each cell on which formatting is applied it will check wheter corresponding cell defined by algorithm meets the condition. Here it is "John".

Then you copy this rule for all the names and define color for each name.

[image]

My solution file is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z2bdeEBpYJX16xZk6apgfPgMGerCReaXCKq2Ay1RZ10/copy

Comment: I would assume the formula would change depending on the region size and locations? I made an example on Sheet 2 of my test sheet.

Comment: I'm currently trying to modify the above formula to match my second example. If two formulas are needed, one for each top region of a section, and one for the bottom region of a section, that would be OK.

Comment: Yes. The only problem in this task is to define the way the formula finds all the relevant references (names) and applies formatting to cells. As you saw, I defined an algorithm that returns address for each name location.

Comment: I was wondering if you could expand on how you created the algorithm. Say if you wanted to create a formula for anything smaller then column 21, then display 15 then so on and so on.

6*int((column()-2)/6)+2 indicates anything smaller then 8, then display 2. Does that come from the 6 + 2 at the end?